# SOAPUI ReadyAPI resource parameter in URL

Tags: rest, parameters, soapui, ready-api

Is there a way to have a parameter at the end of the URL for a Rest request?

This is the URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/my_user/1000
```

I've tried to use a parameter for the 1000, like so:

```
http://localhost:8000/my_user/${#Project#id_test}
```

This doesn't render 1000 at the end.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Tom, can you check the solution to see if that helps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are REST resource parameter types.

In your case, **style** should be `Template`. That should resolve the issue.

To give an example:

While adding a new REST Resource from API use below url instead of plain text value.

[image]

In the request you would see as below:

[image]

Now, in your test cases, you can use the property expression (the one you were using in the question) i.e., `${#Project#id_test}` for `value` field/column as underline in the above image.

You may also go thru [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/understanding-rest-parameters.html) if needed.

Comment: Thank you Rao, I was away over the weekend.  I'll give this a go today and accept as answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is possible, though I'm not sure about the value you have supplied.

When you set up a RESTful Test Project is SoapUI, you define the root/base url under test.

When you set up the service call in SoapUI, you define the GET, POST settings.  In the same place, you can add parameters.  Click on the Request tab and you should see an empty table with headings, Name, Value, Style, Level.

You can add your parameter here.

E.g.

```
   Name | Value | Style | Level
   id   | Smith | QUERY | RESOURCE
```

When you run the service call and you not sure your request is correct, click on the Raw tab and that will show what SoapUI is actually sending to your service.